# off by one when trying to solve the sum of a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{27}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1}+\cdots$$

If I use the formula $S=\dfrac{a}{1-r}$ where the first term in the sequence is $a=1/3,$ and the common ratio is $ r=-1/3$, I get the sum of the sequence to be $S=1/4$

If I try to solve the summation using summation notation after factoring out $-1/3$, I have an off by one error.

$$\frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{3})(-\frac{1}{3})^n =-\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n =-1/12$$

In comparison,

$$\frac{1}{3} \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n =\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3}} =1/4$$

Why is it that I match the solution by using $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$ instead of $\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{3})^{n+1}$ ?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^0$$ There's your off-by-one.

Comment: Until one is fully comfortable with summation notation, and even afterwards, it is useful to "check" manipulations by looking at the first couple of terms.